# Radbutton is displaying clearly after clicking

Tags: asp.net

Radbutton is not displaying properly after clicking. Recently Telerik released an update. After updating locally we're facing this issue. Please find the screen shot in the attachment.

Before clicking the button looks fine. It is named as first.png in the attachment. And after clicking the button, we're facing the problem. It is named as second.png in the attachment.

Before clicking:

[image: Before clicking]

After clicking:

[image: After Clicking]

Answer (score 0):

try  to check a few things:

1. If second.png is loading correctly
2. If there are any errors on console while running any js code(if there is any) associated with button click.
3. If there is a div in html, which might overlap the button, which is made visible on button click.